# css field position are change when "X" icon appeard [it should be the same with title], anyone know the solution?

Tags: css, vue.js

[image]I am fixing the field in a page, when I want to add 1 more field, the "X" icon will appear inline the field, and the other field will change position to adjust the icon position, but I want to make it same with the title, how can I make the field stay the sam position while having the "X" icon in the same line?

CSS

```
[
.account-csv-field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 2.8rem;
  &.all-edit-disabled { height: 1rem; }
  .ie-field {
    margin: 0 0.1rem;
    height: 2.8rem;
    &.ie-user {
      flex: 1;
      max-width: 13rem;
    }
    &.ie-password {
      flex: 1;
      max-width: 13rem;
    }
    &.ie-comm-plan {
      flex: 1;
      max-width: 13rem;
    }
    &.ie-model {
      flex: 1;
    }
    &.ie-option {
      flex: 1;
      width: 12px;
    }
  }
.ie-close-button {
    font-size: 20pt;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    cursor: grab;
  }]
```

HTML

```
<nc-select
      v-if="!account.fromCsv || (initialErrorState.option && !forceEditDisable)"
      class="ie-option ie-field"
      :value="account.option.value"
      :options="options.map(c => c['option'])"
      :error-popup="errorState.option"
      :disabled="options.length < 1 && !account.option.value"
      :required="options.length > 0"
      :error-without-interaction="account.fromCsv"
      @update:value="updateIssuing('option', $event)">
    </nc-select>
    <el-tooltip v-else :content="errorState.option" :disabled="!errorState.option" placement="top" effect="light">
      <span :class="{ 'static-error': Boolean(errorState.option) }" class="cell-option">{{ account.option.value }}</span>
    </el-tooltip>
    <i
      class="el-icon-close ie-close-button"
      v-show="removable"
      @click="$emit('remove')"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` to following class `.ie-close-button` and provide `position:relative` to its parent dom. then you can adjust the close postion according to your wish using `left and right` properties

Comment: thank you for your answer, I already tried it, but the field arrow will be behind "X" icon if I do that